# jQuery: on click change similar elements with global code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a simple code where when I click on one of the 'chevron' jquery show hided content.

But this code is completly for each one different.

Is there any solution how to make one global code to effect every element with this functionality?

In my original code, I have more elements like this.

**My code:**

```js
$('.chevron1').click(function() {
  $('.more-fix-broken-links').toggleClass('active');
});
$('.chevron2').click(function() {
  $('.more-spelling-grammar').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 10px
}

.chevron {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.chevron.active {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.more-fix-broken-links {
  max-width: 280px;
  display: none;
}

.more-spelling-grammar {
  max-width: 280px;
  display: none;
}

.more-fix-broken-links.active {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}

.more-spelling-grammar.active {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column">
  <div>
    <input id="fix-broken-links" type="checkbox">
    <label for="fix-broken-links">Fix broken links</label>
    <img class="chevron1" src="https://supersede.space/chevron.svg" alt="Checklist chevron">
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="more-fix-broken-links">SKuska skuskaSKuska skuskaSKuska skuskaSKuska skuskaSKuska skuska</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <div>
    <input id="spelling-grammar" type="checkbox">
    <label for="spelling-grammar">Spelling & grammar</label>
    <img class="chevron2" src="https://supersede.space/chevron.svg" alt="Checklist chevron">
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="more-spelling-grammar">SKuska skuskaSKuska skuskaSKuska skuskaSKuska skuskaSKuska skuska</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use parent element too, like this. On my example, using 2 `.parent()` brings you to a `.column` level, and from that point you start search of tag `p` using `.find('p')`. Or you can set a specific class to `p` element ant search for them.

```js
$('.chevron').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active'); // for you css .chevron.active 
  $(this).parent().parent().find('p').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 10px
}

.chevron {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.chevron.active {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.more-fix-broken-links {
  max-width: 280px;
  display: none;
}

.more-spelling-grammar {
  max-width: 280px;
  display: none;
}

.more-fix-broken-links.active {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}

.more-spelling-grammar.active {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column">
  <div>
    <input id="fix-broken-links" type="checkbox">
    <label for="fix-broken-links">Fix broken links</label>
    <img class="chevron" src="https://supersede.space/chevron.svg" alt="Checklist chevron">
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="more-fix-broken-links">SKuska skuskaSKuska skuskaSKuska skuskaSKuska skuskaSKuska skuska</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <div>
    <input id="spelling-grammar" type="checkbox">
    <label for="spelling-grammar">Spelling & grammar</label>
    <img class="chevron" src="https://supersede.space/chevron.svg" alt="Checklist chevron">
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="more-spelling-grammar">SKuska skuskaSKuska skuskaSKuska skuskaSKuska skuskaSKuska skuska</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store each class and the corresponding paragraph class in a `set` and get the clicked element class as follows:

```js
let set = {
     'chevron1':'.more-fix-broken-links',
     'chevron2':'.more-spelling-grammar'
}
$('.chevron1, .chevron2').click(function(e) {
     $(set[e.target.className]).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
img {
     width: 10px
}
.chevron {
     cursor: pointer;
}
.chevron.active {
     transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.column {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
}
.more-fix-broken-links {
     max-width: 280px;
     display: none;
}
.more-spelling-grammar {
     max-width: 280px;
     display: none;
}
.more-fix-broken-links.active {
     display: block;
     height: 100%;
}
.more-spelling-grammar.active {
     display: block;
     height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column">
     <div>
          <input id="fix-broken-links" type="checkbox">
          <label for="fix-broken-links">Fix broken links</label>
          <img class="chevron1" src="https://supersede.space/chevron.svg" alt="Checklist chevron">
     </div>
     <div>
          <p class="more-fix-broken-links">SKuska skuskaSKuska skuskaSKuska skuskaSKuska skuskaSKuska skuska</p>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="column">
      <div>
           <input id="spelling-grammar" type="checkbox">
           <label for="spelling-grammar">Spelling & grammar</label>
           <img class="chevron2" src="https://supersede.space/chevron.svg" alt="Checklist chevron">
      </div>
      <div>
           <p class="more-spelling-grammar">SKuska skuskaSKuska skuskaSKuska skuskaSKuska skuskaSKuska skuska</p>
      </div>
</div>
```